# How to optimize drawing these markers?

Tags: java, performance, swing, drawing

I'am currently working on graphing program in Java/Swing. Currently I made `JPanel` with axes and markers on it.

My question is how can I merge loops for drawing  negative with positive value markers?

Currently I made something like this:

```
 private void DrawAxisMarkers(Graphics g) {

    //X  MARKERS
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    for (int xI = 0; xI <= this.getWidth(); xI += MatherProperties.SCALE) {
        g.drawLine(xI * MatherProperties.SCALE+ origin.x, markerSize + origin.y, xI * MatherProperties.SCALE + origin.x, -markerSize + origin.y);
    }
    for (int xI = 0; xI <= this.getWidth(); xI += MatherProperties.SCALE) {
        g.drawLine(-xI * MatherProperties.SCALE + origin.x, markerSize + origin.y, -xI * MatherProperties.SCALE + origin.x, -markerSize + origin.y);
    }

    //Y MARKERS
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    for (int yI = 0; yI <= this.getHeight(); yI += MatherProperties.SCALE) {
        g.drawLine(markerSize + origin.x, yI * MatherProperties.SCALE + origin.y, -markerSize + origin.x, yI * MatherProperties.SCALE + origin.y);
    }
    for (int yI = 0; yI <= this.getHeight(); yI += MatherProperties.SCALE) {
        g.drawLine(markerSize + origin.x, -yI * MatherProperties.SCALE + origin.y, -markerSize + origin.x, -yI * MatherProperties.SCALE + origin.y);
    }
}
```

I don't have any ideas how to merge them :\ Also the origin of these axes is in the middle but user will be able to change origin.

The graph:

[image]

Comment: Move `g.drawLine(-xI * MatherProperties.SCALE + origin.x, markerSize + origin.y, -xI * MatherProperties.SCALE + origin.x, -markerSize + origin.y);` up  so it is within the first loop.  Similar for the y-axis.

Comment: @AndrewS I'm such an idiot ;-;

Comment: Nah - that's what reviews are for!

Comment: Remove the second loop and make the first loop go from `-this.getWidth()` to `this.getWidth()` - or turn the g.drawLine call into a method that takes xI as an argument so that you can call it with both -xI and xI

Comment: Anyway, Thanks for help!